# Fallo con do-while

Tags: c++, while

En este programa, la función do-while no hace lo que debería, mi intención es que pida de nuevo el mes en el que estamos siempre que sea menor que 1 y mayor que 12.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(){
    int year;
    int m;

    cout << "Introduce anio" << endl;
    cin >> year;

    do{
        cout << "Introduce mes" << endl;
        cin >> m;
    }while(m < 1 && m > 12);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: No hay problema con el Do While, el problema es tu logica dentro del while, porque nunca te dara verdadero, ya que debe cumplir las dos condiciones para seguir funcionando, debes usar el operador ( OR  || ) para que cumpla una de las dos condiciones.

Answer (score 1):

Te falla el operador lógico. En tu programa le estás diciendo que m sea menor que 1 Y mayor que 12. No hay ningún entero que cumpla con esa condición por lo que
`while(m < 1 && m > 12);` siempre te va a dar false. Tienes que reemplazarlo por

```
while(m < 1 || m > 12);
```

Answer (score 1):

Yo no se mucho de programación, pero creo que lo que falla es la expresión `&&`, con eso lo que pides es que se ejecute el *do-while* si m es menor que 1 y mayor que 12 a la vez. Sustitúyelo por un `||`, así se ejecutará siempre que se cumpla una de las dos condiciones.

Answer (score 0):

Has un console log a:

```
while(m < 1 || m > 12)
```

y

```
while(m < 1 && m > 12);
```

Podrás visualizar la salida e identificar el error.

Comment: Esa respuesta no corrige el error de su codigo, ya que su error es meramente logico dentro del while, la sentencias del codigo funcionan perfecto hace decadas.

Comment: `m < 1 && m > 12` Da Falso para cualquier valor de m.

Answer (score 0):

Lo correcto seria utilizar una sentencia ||, ya que tu querrías solicitar introducir un dato siempre y cuando m sea menor que 1 y además sea mayor que 12
por tanto la condición del while debería ser de la siguiente forma:

```
while(m < 1 || m > 12)
```

Así comprobaría que la m esta en el siguiente rango de valores:
1 > m < 12.

Quedando tu código de la siguiente manera:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(){
    int year;
    int m;

    cout << "Introduce anio" << endl;
    cin >> year;

    do{
        cout << "Introduce mes" << endl;
        cin >> m;
    }while(m < 1 || m > 12);

    return 0;
}
```